# android list item's child view with rounded corners

Tags: android, list, rounded-corners

I am developing an Alarm Clock application. I want an activity to list all the existing alarms. I am using a custom layout for each row of the ListView. It should display the alarm's description, type and the time.

Here is the row layout: alarm_item_2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:background="@drawable/selector">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/time_background"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:textSize="36sp"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/time"
        android:paddingTop="6dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#000"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/type"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/time"
        android:layout_below="@id/description"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#000"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Also the layout for the activity: view_alarms.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          >
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="#fff"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

What I want is to make the view displaying the time be black and with round corners. I am using a shape resource: time_background_xml in res/drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#000000"/>
    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

However, the background of the button remains white. What is the problem with my code? Obviously, I'm missing something important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the time_background_xml should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#000000"/>    
            <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>    
</layer-list>
```

Take a look at [this](http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.com/2011/07/design-linearlayout-or-textview-and-any.html) for more help.

**UPDATE:**

I think this will work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle"> 
    <solid android:color="#000000"/>    

    <stroke android:width="3dp"
            android:color="#000000"/>

    <padding android:left="1dp"
             android:top="1dp"
             android:right="1dp"
             android:bottom="1dp"/> 

    <corners android:radius="10dp"/> 
</shape>
```

Also, take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/shapes/RoundRectShape.html) for an alternative solution.

Comment: It is not working. The background is still transparent. <layer-list> is good when used to draw multiple items, but in my layout, I only need a black rectangle with rounded corners, so a simple <shape> should normally suffice.